# Почему использование empty() для определения наличия у объекта свойства - плохая идея?

Tags: php, ооп, property

Продублирую вопрос:
Почему использование empty() для определения наличия у объекта свойства - плохая идея?

Comment: Вы **действительно** дублируете вопрос? Если да, какой и зачем?

Comment: Написано ж в документации: *Проверяет, считается ли переменная пустой. Переменная считается пустой, если она не существует или её значение равно FALSE.*

Comment: @VladD автор дублирует свой же заголовок

Comment: @Etki: А, понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, безотносительно к объектам, использование empty() для проверки существования **вообще любой переменной**  - плохая идея. Поскольку для проверки существования служит функция `isset()`. А `empty()` вернет `TRUE` для кучи существующих переменных.

Во-вторых, если сделать вопрос адекватным, изменив формулировку на "использование empty() для проверки свойства объекта", то это была плохая идея до версии 5.1, в которой появился магический метод `__isset()`.
Который в обязательном порядке надо реализовывать, если в объекте используются виртуальные свойства, реализуемые методом `__get()`.

Собственно, виртруальные свойства - это и есть та при чина, по которой ответ `empty()` или `isset()` на свойство объекта может быть неверным.

```
class a
{
        protected $data = array(
                'prop1' => 1,
                'prop2' => 2,
        );

        public function __get($name)
        {
                if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
                        return $this->data[$name];
                } else {
                        throw new Exception("Undefined property $name");
                }
        }
#       public function __isset($name) 
#       {
#               return isset($this->data[$name]);
#       }
}

$a = new a;
var_dump($a->prop1);
var_dump(empty($a->prop1));
var_dump(empty($a->prop3));
```

если раскомментировать `__isset()` то проверка начнет работать правильно.

А вообще, чтобы не заставлять отвечающих гадать, надо приводить ссылку на источник высказывания.